# Usage of tf.GraphKeys

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, there's a class `GraphKeys`. I came across many codes, where it's been used. But it's not explained very well what's the usage of this class both in tensorflow documentation as well as in the codes, where it has been used.

Can someone please explain what's the usage of `tf.GraphKey`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, `tf.GraphKeys` is a collection of collections of keys for variables and ops in the graph. The usage (just as common python dictionaries) is to retrieve variables and ops.

Given that said, here are some subsets of `tf.GraphKeys` I came across:

- `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` and `LOCAL_VARIABLES` contain all variables of the graph, which need to be initialized before training. `tf.global_variables()` returns the global variables in a list and can be used with `tf.variables_initializer` for initialization.
- Variables created with option `trainable=True` will be added to `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` and will be fetched and updated by any optimizer under `tf.train` during training.
- `SUMMARIES` contains keys for all summaries added by `tf.summary` (`scalar`, `image`, `histogram`, `text`, etc). `tf.summary.merge_all` gathers all such keys and returns an op to be run and written to file so that you can visualize them on tensorboard.
- Custom functions to update some variables can be added to `UPDATE_OPS` and separately run at each iteration using `sess.run(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))`. In this case, these variables are set `trainable=False` to avoid being updated by gradient descent.
- You may create your own collections using `tf.add_to_collection(some_name, var_or_op)` and retrieve the variable or op later. You may retrieve specific variables or ops using `tf.get_collection()` and tweak the `scope`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And sorry for replying late.So what you are saying is `tf.GraphKeys` is a `list` of "attributes" from the tensorflow graph. If that's the case, then what's the use of it? We can anyway call any of the graph attributed from `meta` or `ckpt` file.

Comment: @Beta Well...they are different things...`meta` and `ckpt` files store the graph on hard drive, `GraphKeys` are more like lists of pointers to memory. `GraphKeys` are continually added when you define variables and ops in a graph, and are used mostly by TensorFlow ops backend. Using metaphor, if graph is a PDF file, `GraphKeys` would be the table of contents while `meta` and `ckpt` are the book in your hand.